# HDD password is frozen and disk read error

Tags: hard-drive, boot, password-protection

I have a Samsung N102SP and it is not booting.

It says

> A disk read error occured, Press ctrl+alt+dlt to restart.

I thought the HDD is bad, but then I booted using Backtrack and I was able to access the HDD.

I backed up all data and there was no problem in accessing the HDD. But in BIOS the HDD password is frozen.

So I tried to install Windows and the installation goes smoothly without any error [deleted all partitions and created new ones]. But when I try to boot from HDD the same error shows up again [disk read error].

So, I temporarily cleared the HDD password but it won't boot from HDD and the HDD password goes back to frozen. Also, the owner of the lap had never set any HDD password. I was informed that the lap fell down once but it worked fine until now. Whats happening?

It just can't boot from HDD but I was able to access it from Backtrack and was able to complete installation of Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If wiping, partitioning, formatting and installing a fresh OS doesn't make it boot, then (and even before then, based on your description) it sounds like the drive is failing.

Try a known-good HDD and see if it works any better.

If you don't have a one to try, take it to a repair shop.

Comment: Ya. I think I should take it to a repair shop. This one is a Netbook and is there any difference in HDD when comparing with Laptops?

Comment: Depends on the Netbook, but yeah often they're just tiny [mSATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#Mini-SATA_.28mSATA.29) SSD's.